# Why does the Maclaurin serie of $(1+x)^k$ converge only for $|x|< 1$?

Tags: convergence-divergence, power-series, taylor-expansion, binomial-coefficients

So I understand that if $f(x)=(1+x)^k$ you get something like
\begin{align}
f(x)=(1+x)^k  \Rightarrow f(0)=1\\
f'(x)=k(1+x)^k  \Rightarrow f'(0)=k\\
\vdots\\
f^{(n)}(x)=k(k-1)\dots (k-n+1)x^{k-n} \Rightarrow f^{(n)}(0)= \frac{k!}{(k-n)!}
\end{align}

However, for any fixed $k$ and since $n$ goes from $0$ to $\infty$, then eventually $n=k$ and so $f^{(k)}(x)=k!$ and $f^{(k)}(0)=k!$ but $f^{(k+1)}(x)=0$. Therefore when doing the Maclaurin serie you will get a lot of $0's$ such that
$$ f(x)=(x+1)^k=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} {k\choose n} x^{n} = \sum_{n=0}^{k} {k\choose n} x^{n}$$
and since it is a finite sum, then it should converge for any $x$. I understand that the $|x|<1$ comes y applying the Ratio test when
$$\lim_{n\to \infty} \left\vert \frac{k! \; x^{n+1}}{(n+1)!(k-n-1)!} \times \frac{n!(k-n)!}{k! \; x^n}\right\vert=\lim_{n\to \infty} \left\vert x \frac{k-n}{n+1}\right\vert=\vert x \vert$$
However in this case it looks as if one is assuming that $k>n$ for the factorials to be defined, which is not the case if $k$ is fixed.

Where did I go wrong?

Comment: What is $\frac{(k-n)!}{(k-n-1)!}$ when $n \geq k$?

Comment: What if $k$ is not an nonnegative integer?

Comment: Clearly, it depends on the value of $\,k.\,$ If it is a non-negative integer, then $\,(1+x)^k\,$ is a polynomial and this finite sum converges for all $\,x.$ Otherwise, yes, you need $\,|x|<1.$

Comment: Okay I didn't considered the case when $k$ wasn't a nonnegative integer. However, how can you define a negative factorial? Maybe $(-1)^n (|n|!)$?

Comment: @leplata The Maclaurin series of $(1 + x)^k$ is $$\sum_{n = 0}^{+\infty} \frac{\mathrm d^n}{ \mathrm d^n x}[(1 + x)^k] \bigg |_{x = 0} \cdot \frac{x^n}{n!}$$ Only the usual factorial $n!$ defined for $n = 0, 1, 2, \dots$ is needed.